# entity framework inserting new entity

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, data-annotations, entity-framework-5

I am using the latest Entity Framework with a code-first approach.
I have such classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class Customer
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CustomerInitials { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Customer")]
        public virtual List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Transaction
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Transactions")]
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to enter a new entry, I find the respective customer from the `IDbSet<Customer>`
in my context and call

```
customer.Transactions.Add(newTrasnaction)
context.SaveChanges();
```

which gives me `Invalid column name 'CustomerInitials'`, which is a normal varchar column in the `Customers` table. Loading all data works just fine, just saving that has a problem.

**Some additional details:** When creating the new transaction, I don't set the Customer property, just CustomerId. Not sure if this is related to this problem or not.

Comment: It all looks fine to me, are you 100% sure that Customer has a 'CustomerInitials' column in the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh stupid me for not looking deeper into the exception. It came out there was an error an insert trigger for the table.